# How to push data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

there is an issue when I'm adding data to list with a function called addGroup.It is giving me this type-error:

```
   "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"
    at r.$scope.addGroup (main.js:7)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13365), <anonymous>:4:215)
    at e (angular.js:23613)
    at r.$eval (angular.js:16052)
    at r.$apply (angular.js:16152)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23618)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12520
(anonymous) @ angular.js:9292
$apply @ angular.js:16157
(anonymous) @ angular.js:23618
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

html code:

```
<ul ng-repeat = "info in infos | filter:curInfo.name">
       <img src="{{info.image.link}}"/> {{info.name}}
        <li ng-repeat="group in info.groups | filter: curInfo" 
            ng-bind-html="group.name | highlight:curInfo.name">
           <a href="#">{{group.name}}</a>
        </li>
             <div class="add list">
                <a href="" ng-click="addGroup()">+Add group </a>
             </div>
    </ul>
```

js code:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope , dataService){
        $scope.addGroup = function () {
            var group = {name: "This is a new group"};
            $scope.infos.push(group);
        };
```

json data

```
[
   {
      "id":736,
      "name":"Systems",
      "image":{
         "link":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KA9j.jpg?s=32&g=1"
      },
      "groups":[
         {
            "id":2168,
            "name":"API",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/api/"
         },
         {
            "id":11955,
            "name":"Assets",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/assets/"
         },
         {
            "id":3179,
            "name":"Design",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/design/"
         },
         {
            "id":207,
            "name":"Development",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/development/"
         },
         {
            "id":70,
            "name":"Intranet",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/intranet/"
         }
      ],
      "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/projects"
   },
   {
      "id":44315,
      "name":"User Agents",
      "image":{
         "link":"http://www.zerohedge.com/sites/default/files/pictures/picture5781.jpg"
      },
      "groups":[
         {
            "id":191599,
            "name":"Alchemy",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/tools/alchemy"
         },
         {
            "id":86822,
            "name":"Empathy",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/tools/empathy"
         },
         {
            "id":86297,
            "name":"Epiphany",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/tools/epiphany"
         },
         {
            "id":131837,
            "name":"Harmony",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/tools/hamony"
         },
         {
            "id":174338,
            "name":"Zagreb",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/tools/zagreb"
         }
      ],
      "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/tools"
   }
]
```

I have used a navigation bar to show this data. the "groups" part is shown in

and now I want the addGroup function to add new list items but it is added in ul tag.

Comment: above the `addGroup` declaration, put: `$scope.infos = [];` You need something to push to.

Comment: @tavnab hi, this worked but I wanted to add it to a <li> and it added to a <ul>. could u help me with that?

Comment: Please update your question with what the structure of `infos` should be. It's not clear what you're trying to do without knowing how you expect `infos` and its members to be structured.

Comment: @tavnab i have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue seems to be an uninitialized `$scope.infos` variable. I'm guessing this variable's contents are fetched via your `dataService` service, and that your intention is to push to the `groups` member of some element of `$scope.infos`.

To do that, your `addGroups` will need to know which `groups` to push into, so either `info` or `info.groups` will need to be passed in as a parameter (I went with the latter).

Here's a pared down version of what I think you're trying to accomplish.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.factory('dataService', ['$q', function($q) {
  //dummy service simulating actual dataService
  
  var infos = [
   {
      "id":736,
      "name":"Systems",
      "image":{
         "link":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KA9j.jpg?s=32&g=1"
      },
      "groups":[
         {
            "id":2168,
            "name":"API",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/api/"
         },
         {
            "id":11955,
            "name":"Assets",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/assets/"
         },
         {
            "id":3179,
            "name":"Design",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/design/"
         },
         {
            "id":207,
            "name":"Development",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/development/"
         },
         {
            "id":70,
            "name":"Intranet",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/intranet/"
         }
      ],
      "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/projects"
   },
   {
      "id":44315,
      "name":"User Agents",
      "image":{
         "link":"http://www.zerohedge.com/sites/default/files/pictures/picture5781.jpg"
      },
      "groups":[
         {
            "id":191599,
            "name":"Alchemy",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/tools/alchemy"
         },
         {
            "id":86822,
            "name":"Empathy",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/tools/empathy"
         },
         {
            "id":86297,
            "name":"Epiphany",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/tools/epiphany"
         },
         {
            "id":131837,
            "name":"Harmony",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/tools/hamony"
         },
         {
            "id":174338,
            "name":"Zagreb",
            "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/tools/zagreb"
         }
      ],
      "url":"https://wwww.itschools.co.za/tools"
    }
  ];
  
  return {
    infos: function() {
      return $q.resolve(infos);
    }
  }
}])

.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService',
function($scope, dataService) {
  dataService.infos().then(function(infos) {
    $scope.infos = infos;
  });
  
  $scope.addGroup = function(groups) {
    var group = {name: "This is a new group"};
    groups.push(group);
  };
}])

;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <!-- filter and highlight stuff removed for simplicity -->
    <ul ng-repeat = "info in infos">
      <img src="{{info.image.link}}"/> {{info.name}}
      <li ng-repeat="group in info.groups">
         <a ng-href="{{group.url}}">{{group.name}}</a>
      </li>
      <div class="add list">
        <a href="" ng-click="addGroup(info.groups)">+Add group </a>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `dataService` is mocked up since it wasn't provided in the question, but it should be clear on how to transform that into something that could fetch the contents via e.g. the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

One other change was to use `ng-href="{{group.url}}"` on your per-group `<a>`s; it wasn't mentioned but I assumed that's what the url member was for.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope , dataService){
        $scope.addGroup = function () {
            $scope.infos = [];
            var group = {name: "This is a new group"};
            $scope.infos.push(group);
        };
```

Comment: This will reset `$scope.infos` to an empty array every time before pushing to it; you'll only ever have one item in your array. Consider initializing it outside of `addGroup`